# Transpose varying number of rows till varying number of blank appears VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have a data like below. The blocks separated by blanks belong to one unit of information, but the blanks are inconsistent, sometimes one row sometimes two or more and sometimes none.
[image]

I am aiming to achieve the output as below:-
[image]

I am quite new to VBA. What i have attempted so far is below:-

```
Range("A1:A" & nlr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "" 'nlr is the last row of data calculated
Range("H2:H" & nlr).Formula = "=COUNTA(A2:G2)"   'Data is from A to G Column  

For i = 2 To nlr 
   If Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And Range("K" & i).Value <= 3 Then
       Range("I" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
       Range("J" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 1).Value
       Range("K" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 2).Value
       Range("L" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 3).Value
    End If
Next
```

Also referred to below solutions, but didn't work for me

[VBA Transposing a dynamic range in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403353/vba-transposing-a-dynamic-range-in-excel)

[Excel VBA Transpose Variable Column Range to Variable Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480022/excel-vba-transpose-variable-column-range-to-variable-rows)

Any help is highly appreciated !!

Comment: It's not clear from your screen shot exactly what the rules for consolidation are. Values from the first row in each block seem to be ignored?

Comment: Also unclear are the rules for consolidation of your 3rd (last) block. In that block a number of the items don't seem to be in the correct column.  And there are two rows of entries for it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should expose enough information to help you: Criteria are not clear, some of the code is not already there (nlr declaration). Some issues that seems to not to be clear:  If you place _.Formula = "=COUNTA(A2:G2)"_, then it will not work against each line, just against A2:G2; if you are counting the values at column H and later you are searching at K, condition will not work, at your code, you are copying 4 items from I to L, but at your screenshot there are just 3. Please, edit your question to clarify

Comment: I am sorry if i am unclear. So, basically it is transposing the rows to columns till it finds a blank and re-start transposing with next block of information for next row. So if data is in column A from 2 to 4th or 5th row it should get transposed as first row. And next non blank should get transposed as second row and so on.

Comment: Count was my effort to fix some condition where it knows that how many rows need to be transposed. But id didn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel sorry for not able to stop trying for this request, although in future it is not advisable to seek answer for ready code to produce the result, anyway please find the code below for your need, accept if help and take time to understand what am I writing in the code :)

```
Sub t()

Dim rawData As Variant, tranData As Variant
Dim copyrange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long, blankRow As Long, nonBlankRow As Long, irow As Long, findNextRow As Long
Dim destiRow As Long, countV As Long, copytimes As Long, detailsrow As Long, repeatTime As Long
Dim addcontact As Long, copyAddContact As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
blankRow = 0
repeatTime = 1

For irow = 2 To lastrow
    repeatTime = 1
    destiRow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A" & irow).Value) Then
        blankRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & irow).Row - 1
        countV = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("B" & blankRow - 4, "B" & blankRow))
        rawData = Sheet1.Range("A" & blankRow - 4, "A" & blankRow).Value
        tranData = Application.Transpose(rawData)
        
        For copytimes = 1 To countV
            Set copyrange = Sheet2.Range("A" & destiRow + copytimes, "E" & destiRow + copytimes)
            copyrange.Value = tranData
        Next
        
        For detailsrow = countV To 1 Step -1
            Sheet1.Range("B" & blankRow - (detailsrow - 1), "F" & blankRow - (detailsrow - 1)).Copy _
            Sheet2.Range("F" & destiRow + repeatTime, "I" & destiRow + repeatTime)
            repeatTime = repeatTime + 1
        Next
        
        
        For findNextRow = blankRow + 1 To lastrow
            If Not IsEmpty(Sheet1.Range("A" & findNextRow).Value) Then
                irow = findNextRow - 1
                addcontact = irow - blankRow
                For copyAddContact = 1 To addcontact
                    Sheet2.Cells(destiRow + countV, 10 + copyAddContact).Value = Sheet1.Range("F" & blankRow + copyAddContact).Value
                Next
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
        
Next

End Sub
```

Raw data in Sheet1 ( please take note you cannot include extra contact after last row 21, it will be your challenge to find out if the code can be adjusted for real business case)
[image]

And here is what you are looking for !
[image]

Sheet2 here is refer to the sheet code name (sheetname can be change)

[image]

Comment: I genuinely appreciate your help & really thank you for this. But it is giving the error "Run-time error '424' Object Required"
 for this line of code 
"destiRow = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count".

Comment: Do  you have add a sheet2? You also need to add the header

Comment: Yes Kin, i have sheet 2 added & added headers. It's still giving the same error. Please help me resolve this

Comment: How is it going? I am sure it work, accept my answer if help, appreciate my one hour work on this :)

Comment: Kin - I am really thankful & appreciate your help. Your solution is perfect. However, I have a data which is far more messy than this. This was a part of the whole problem & helped me a lot.. Thanks once again !!!

Comment: Welcome, it is interesting case study on data analyst, the real life is much complicate and messy than i can imagine, hope you can find a solution to fix all issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton, could you please also help me with this piece of code, It's giving application defined or object defined error.
     For Each c In Range("B1:B" & nlr).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
          n = c.Row
          c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:B " & n - 1 & "<>""),$B$1:B " & n - 1 & ")"
     Next

Comment: Hmm, it is hard to see what is the main reason for error, maybe you can open new thread, either me or others are always willing give you a help :)

Comment: I am unable to start a new thread due to low points, :(

Comment: ok, i upvote you already, check if you can raise new question? First time hear it

Comment: sorry, still can't

Comment: Then try create new account to ask lol. I check that you need to wait as least 6 month to ask new question, omg...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67683618/using-variable-name-in-lookup-formula-vba
Please refer to this question

Comment: See, an expert is helping your now, hope it solve your issue :)

Comment: Not Really, I had already tried that way, but it didn't work either, :(

Comment: lol, why you delete your account after asking the question, they spot it already..