# Using Variable Name in Lookup Formula VBA

Tags: excel, vba

It may seem to be an easy one as i am novice at VBA. I am trying to fill the filtered blank visible cells with previous non blank hidden cell value in the same column. The Lookup formula is working fine on excel sheet but using it with variable range in VBA is  giving Application defined or object defined Error on lookup formula line.

```
nlr = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
With Activehseet
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Range("A1:K" & nlr).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=""
  Range("A1:K" & nlr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="P * Suite *"
  Range("B2:B" & nlr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
  For Each c In Range("B1:B" & nlr).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      n = c.Row - 1
      c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B&n&<>""),$B$2:B&n&)"
```

I have already tried it with  below too, but it didn't work

```
    c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B " & n & "<>""),$B$2:B" & n & ")"
```

Please help me resolve this

EDIT: I have already tried this approach, but it didn't work either

```
c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B " & n & "<>""""),$B$2:B" & n & ")"
```

Comment: The user already deleted his account after asking the question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has deleted the account after asking the question. We will never know if the solution(s) ever solved OPs problem. It will be a waste of time to spend any time on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct approach for concatenating a string into another string:

```
c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B " & n & "<>""),$B$2:B" & n & ")"
```

However, there is a problem with this part of it:

```
... & n & "<>""), ...
```

That will place *one* double quote into the text.  I presume you are expecting it to look like `<>""` when parsed, which means the line should look like this:

```
... & n & "<>""""), ...
```

Why?  Because in a string to put *one* double quote you need to put a double, double quote: `""` = `"` (in finished string).  Therefore a double, double quote becomes: `""""` = `""`.

Here is the corrected original code:

```
c.Formula = "=LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:B " & n & "<>""""),$B$2:B" & n & ")"
```